# Laravel 8 display 4th, 5th and 6th elements of a collection

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm trying to show items in rows in Laravel 8. The first row is easy enough. The first 3 items of the collection, using a counter and a foreach loop.

```
$i = 0;

foreach($players as $player){

    $i +=1;

    what to do each loop
    if($i == 3) break;
}
```

But if I want the 4th, 5th and 6th items on the second row, how would I do that? I tried array_slice which didn't work because a collection is not an array. Secondly, apparently, I cannot tell a forEach loop where to start.

Comment: But you can tell a for loop where to start

Comment: Or you could try `foreach($players as $key => $player){` and then a modulus test on $key likke `if ( $key % 3 == 0) {` to throw a new line or start the next line in a table

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a blade, using bootstraps containers, rows and cards:

```html
<div class="container">
@foreach($players as $player)    
    @if($loop->first)
    <div class="row"> //first iteration, start a row
    @endif
    //each element is a cart
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 3px">
        </div>
    </div> 
    @if(($loop->iteration % 3 == 1)&&(!$loop->last))
    //every 3rd iteration, and not the last, end the current row and start a new one
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    @endif
    @if($loop->last)
    </div>//if it's the last iteration, end the row
    @endif
@endforeach
</div>
```

This is just basic array looping, don't have to get complicated or fancy.  More on the Laravel $loop variable here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't get well your use case, but you could use the [`chunck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-chunk) method of the Collection class:

```php
$players = Player::where('...')->get();

$chunks = $players->chunk(3);

foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    foreach($chunk as $player) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or, in case you are in Blade:

```html
@foreach ($players->chunk(3) as $chunk)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($chunk as $player)
            <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $player->name }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `skip()` and `take()` helper function to achieve that. For example.

`Model::skip(3)->take(2)->get();`

will give you the 4th and 5th rows.